# Nginx warning - upstream sent more data

Tags: nginx, php, debian

I have a bunch of Nginx + PHP8.0-fpm installed in the north. When crawlers visit a page and the request contains the If-Modified-Since header, but the page has not changed, the site returns the "304 Not Modified" header. If the request protocol is HTTP / 2.0, everything works correctly, but if the request protocol is HTTP / 1.1, a warning appears in the Nginx logs:

```
[warn] 910 # 910: * 21961 upstream sent more data than specified in "Content-Length" header while reading upstream, client: 66.249.76.145, server: site.com, request: "GET /category/page-title.html HTTP / 1.1 ", upstream:" fastcgi: // unix: /var/www/php-fpm/12345.sock: ", host:"site.com"
```

The site engine does not give Nginx the Content-Length header for sure and there is no content. I tested this by making requests to the site with the If-Modified-Since header via CURL.

Why is Nginx showing this warning? Is this an Nginx bug?

Answer (score 0):

You may be erroneously assuming *there is no content* because Nginx has not forwarded it to you. Take the logged warning as "Nginx *dropped* data the upstream sent even though it should not have sent any".

204/304 is hardcoded to behave like zero content-length. The bug with Nginx is the misleading message - yet it is likely correct about receiving extra data from the fastcgi upstream.

Possibly warning, error or newline (can be avoided by *not* using `?>` in .php files) printed by php *after* returning the status code. It should become visible when you temporarily change the status code returned in your script.

Comment: If this turns out to be correct & you report a bug for Nginx, do reference https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1695 because that would be the reason the warning was implemented this way.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have already found an error in the site engine code. I just could not imagine that the CMC developers would make a gross mistake - they will give data before the header() function.